# Geocoder Sources for Android API 26 Platform Not Found

Tags: android

I just recently reopened my app after maybe a monthlong hiatus from coding only to discover that it doesn't work properly. I have code to display markers from a FireBase database onto a map, which is not working now. Going into the Geocoder.class, it's saying that there are no sources for android api 26 and clicking download does nothing. I've tried "resetting" my api source through the wizard in the SDK manager to no avail. Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 10):

It is quite frustrating not to have API 26 sources but they should be available soon since Android O is due to be released next week. For now though I found the following solution on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6ihzli/targeting_api_26_what_do_to_about_those_missing/) which enables you to use the sources for API 25. I think you need to execute the following commands.

```
cd SDK/sources
cp -R android-25 android-26
cd android-26
vi/emacs/nano package.xml
# Find/replace 25 with 26
vi/emacs/nano source.properties
# Find/replace 25 with 26
```

Then reboot Android Studio. Haven't tried it myself but I hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks, it is working in Sept 25, 2017 under windows 10