# grpc failed geocoder can't resolve android.os.servicemanager

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I'm using android studio. I use GeoCoder.getFromLocation for get latitude and longitude from address but I get java.io.IOException: grpc failed.

I try to use this:
[java.io.IOException: grpc failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012289/java-io-ioexception-grpc-failed)

and this: [Geocoder Sources for Android API 26 Platform Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742894/geocoder-sources-for-android-api-26-platform-not-found)
I unistall Android Studio and reinstall it, but nothing

this is my grandle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.francesco.ester"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-java:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: Is this on an emulator? The geocoding API is currently not working on emulators (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64418751)

Comment: Yes, this is on emulator, but when will there be a solution? So the only solution is to use a physical device